# Change user role programmatically using cron according to Webservice

Tags: 8, cron

On my site I want to set cron job that will check if user already submited form that allow them to browse website freely. I tried to catch user id (and assign a new role id) in `\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Cron.php` using

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
      error_log($user->get('uid')->value);
```

but it seems like it doesn't know context of user and prints just `0`. Is there anyway to do this? Is this even possible in drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to do it by using

```
$user = user_load_by_name('user');
$user->addRole('administrator');
$user->save();
```

that way i got user and i could assign it a designated role.

Unfortunatelly I can't show you webservices handling code due to company policy.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load the user, your are passing the UID of the current user, is it not what you want ?

```
\Drupal::currentUser()->id()
```

I don't have a full vision of what you want, but it should return the current user UID.

Comment: It returns 0 every time

Comment: Because cron is run as the anonymous user (id=0)

Comment: Are you implementing hook_cron() or something else ? You are not trying to directly edit the Cron.php from core ?
Other guess, if you are not connected, you are an anonymous user and UID is always 0

Comment: i was editing Cron.php